# remove every line that contains certain number after bar "|"

Tags: notepad++

I have form that looks this:

```
12345678|123|123|123|123|
12345678|12|123|123|123|
12345678|123|123|123|123|
12345678|12|123|123|123|
```

starts with necessary with 8 random numbers **|** followed by 2 numbers or sometimes 3.

How can I remove every line/full line that contains 8 numbers and followed by three numbers after.

to get the final result:

```
12345678|12|123|123|123|
12345678|12|123|123|123|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d{8}\|\d\d\d\|.+$\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\d{8}       # 8 digits
\|          # a pipe
\d\d\d      # 3 digits
\|          # a pipe
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
\R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: simple and clear! what it woul be to add bar "|" to everytime 4 character occur after 8 number `12345678|1234|123|123|123|` output `12345678|12|34|123|123|123|`

Comment: @Firsthen: Find: `^\d{8}\|\d\d\K(?=\d\d\|)` Replace `|`

Comment: @Firsthen: Find: `^\d{8}\|\d{3}\|\d\d\K(?=\d\d\|)`, but comments are not the place for asking question :)

Comment: (deleted my comment) much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

in notepad++ or any advanced text editor, you can use something called `regex` or regular expressions

`Ctrl+H` to open the replace menu

[image: 1]

```
^(?=[0-9]{0,9})........(?=[0-9]{3,3})*....(?=\|).*
```

input:

```
12345678|123|123|123|123|
12345678|12|123|123|123|
12345678|123|123|123|123|
12345678|12|123|123|123|
```

output:

```
12345678|12|123|123|123|

12345678|12|123|123|123|
```

and to remove the line breaks you can use this

```
/((\r\n|\n|\r)$)|(^(\r\n|\n|\r))|^\s*$/gm
```

final output:

```
12345678|12|123|123|123|
12345678|12|123|123|123|
```

Comment: Why doing this job in two passes? For the 2nd regex, the delimiter and the flags are useless.

Comment: sorry I'm not a regex guy 
I tried my best in the first one 
and the second I copied from another thread